# why doesn't locking a mutex in one thread not block locking the same mutex in a different thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

Basically, I don't understand why this code runs. I was of the belief that locking a mutex would cause other attempts to lock the mutex to block, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

class Foo 
{
  public:
  Foo()
  {
    pThread = boost::make_shared< boost::thread >( [=](){
      boost::unique_lock< boost::mutex >( mtx );
      while( true )
      {   
        fprintf( stdout, "I have the mutex\n");
      }   
    } );
  }

  void bar()
  {
    boost::unique_lock< boost::mutex >( mtx );
    fprintf( stdout, "bar got the mutex\n");
  }

  private:
  boost::mutex mtx;
  boost::shared_ptr< boost::thread > pThread;
};

int main()
{
  Foo foo;
  while( true )
  {
    foo.bar();
  }
}
```

edit:
Output after adding some sleeps so the output is managable.

```
bar got the mutex
I have the mutex
bar got the mutex
I have the mutex
bar got the mutex
I have the mutex
bar got the mutex
I have the mutex
bar got the mutex
I have the mutex
bar got the mutex
I have the mutex
bar got the mutex
I have the mutex
bar got the mutex
I have the mutex
bar got the mutex
I have the mutex
bar got the mutex
I have the mutex
^C
```

This is different from what I reported earlier and this is the updated code. I'm not sure how sleeping threads would affect the output though.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

class Foo 
{
  public:
  Foo()
  {
    pThread = boost::make_shared< boost::thread >( [=](){
      boost::unique_lock< boost::mutex >( mtx );
      while( true )
      {   
        boost::this_thread::sleep( boost::posix_time::milliseconds( 1000 ) );
        fprintf( stdout, "I have the mutex\n");
      }   
    } );
  }

  void bar()
  {
    boost::unique_lock< boost::mutex >( mtx );
    fprintf( stdout, "bar got the mutex\n");
  }

  private:
  boost::mutex mtx;
  boost::shared_ptr< boost::thread > pThread;
};

int main()
{
  Foo foo;
  while( true )
  {
    boost::this_thread::sleep( boost::posix_time::milliseconds( 1000 ) );
    foo.bar();
  }
}
```

Comment: You show the code, and *claim* that the mutex is not locked... but where is your evidence? What output did you actually observe, and what output would've been consistent with a blocked call?

Comment: Are you saying you see `I have the mutex`, followed by `bar got the mutex`? That would indeed be strange. The other way round is not so strange, since `bar` releases the mutex when it returns.

Comment: I think you're using the term *deadlock* incorrectly here. It refers to a case where you have *two* mutexes, and each thread has locked one and is waiting for the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not even locking mutex.

```
boost::unique_lock< boost::mutex >( mtx );
```

It is parsed as declaration of variable `mtx` with type `boost::unique_lock< boost::mutex >`, initialized with default constructor. Instead you need to use constructor that takes reference to lockable object:

```
boost::unique_lock< boost::mutex > lock{mtx};
```

Comment: Haha, thank you for pointing out the oversight. Usually I get a warning or something for that.

Comment: Actually I doubt you would get warning, even worse there is a chance to get warning when you name the variable. I think c++14 should address that issue (if they did not do that already).

Comment: This answer is actually wrong: there is no temporary.  His line defines a local variable of name `mtx`, type `boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>`, initialized with the default constructor (which doesn't actually acquire any mutex.  (This is an original variant on the most embarassing parse.)

Comment: @JamesKanze, thanks. I didn't know you can have variable name in parenthesis (why?).

Comment: @zch, because C. In some declarators the parentheses are needed, e.g. `int (*fp)()`, and so they are part of the grammar for declarators.

Comment: @zch Because the declarator part of a declaration takes the form of an expression, in which parentheses are necessary to control binding.  (Consider the difference between `int *pa[N];` and `int (*pa)[N];`.)  And as is usual for expressions, you can add extra parentheses, even when they aren't needed.